# errror when trying to query a SpList in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an issue while trying to query a Sharepoint list in C# I thought at first it came from a wrong encrypted password but no.

I am getting desperate here if someone has at least a lead for me I'll gladly take it.

Here is my code

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"]) { RequestTimeout = -1 };
var passWord = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in SecureMgr.GetDecryptedPassword(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantPwd"]).ToCharArray()) 
    passWord.AppendChar(c);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TenantLogin"], passWord);
var spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ListAnnuaireUsers"]);
clientContext.Load(spList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The exception catch is this one (I tried translated it from french I hope it's clear enough) : `the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred while sending`

Exception is on this line `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add following code to enable Tls12

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: It was TLS12 indeed